# Regex include the negative lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to filter a string before passing it through `eval` in python.  I want to limit it to math functions, but I'm not sure how to strip it with regex.  Consider the following:

```
s = 'math.pi * 8'
```

I want that to basically translate to 'math.pi*8', stripped of spaces.  I also want to strip any letters `[A-Za-z]` that are not followed by `math\.`.

So if `s = 'while(1): print "hello"'`, I want any executable part of it to be stripped:

s would ideally equal something like `():""` in that scenario (all letters gone, because they were not followed by `math\.`.

Here's the regex I've tried:

```
(?<!math\.)[A-Za-z\s]+
```

and the python:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!math\.)[A-Za-z\s]+', r'', 'math.pi * 8')
```

But the result is `'.p*8'`, because `math.` is not followed by `math.`, and `i` is not followed by `math.`.

How can I strip letters that are not in `math` and are not followed by `math.`?

### What I ended up doing

I followed @Thomas's answer, but also stripped square brackets, spaces, and underscores from the string, in hopes that no python function can be executed other than through the math module:

```
s = re.sub(r'(\[.*?\]|\s+|_)', '', s)
s = eval(s, {
    '__builtins__' : None,
    'math' : math
    })
```

Comment: What is the point of this exercise?

Comment: If your real purpose is to accept user input that you will then evaluate with `eval`, this is not a very safe approach. [This article](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html) provides a safer approach with a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Carl says in a comment, look at what [lybniz does](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html) for something better. But even this is not enough!

The technique described at the link is the following:

```
print eval(raw_input(), {"__builtins__":None}, {'pi':math.pi})
```

But this doesn't prevent something like

```
([x for x in 1.0.__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()
   if x.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'][0]()
   )._module.__builtins__['__import__']('os').system('echo hi!')
```

Source: Several of Ned Batchelder's posts on sandboxing, see http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201302/looking_for_python_3_builtins.html

edit: pointed out that we don't get square brackets or spaces, so:

```
1.0.__class__.__base__.__subclasses__().__getitem__(i)()._module.__builtins__.get('__import__')('os').system('echo hi')
```

where you just try a lot of values for i.

Comment: The raw_input() is converted to a string first, and stripped of square brackets and spaces, so I assume I'm more or less safe.  Thoughts?

Comment: Also, I just tried passing the above script into an eval like lybniz suggests, and it didn't execute (as I had hoped).  Gave an AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__import__'.

Comment: @bozdoz fixed, I forgot that `__builtins__` was a dict somehow in the reformatting

Comment: yeah that got it triggering, even with setting globals in the eval.  Regardless, the string we're passing strips square brackets, so the list comprehension and the dict key won't work.

Comment: @bozdoz fixed brackets and space

Comment: Yes, but you still have `i` within square brackets.  By the way, this is fascinating.

Comment: whoops that should be `__getitem__`

Comment: This has been the most informative and helpful answer I've ever received on SO.